# ASP.NET Core 5 Authorization Policy not detecting claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I'm creating a web API with ASP.NET Core 5 and Identity Framework to handle users.  I'm trying to add an authorization policy that requires a user to have a "canEdit" claim. In my Startup Class, I've added the following code in the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => 
{
    options.AddPolicy("IsUser", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
    options.AddPolicy("CanEdit", policy => policy.RequireClaim("canEdit"));
}
```

In my Configure class I have:

```
// some middleware

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
{
    endpoints.MapControllers()
});
```

I've used this policy in my controller like so:

```
[HttpGet("edit")]
[Authorize(Policy = "CanEdit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditSomething()
{
    \\Stuff here
}
```

The "IsUser" policy works, but the "CanEdit" policy doesn't.  I've got a user with the "canEdit" claim in the AspNetUserClaims table, however when I try to login with this user, I still get a 403 Forbidden response.  I'm using JSON web tokens for authentication.  I've tried adding a "canEdit" claim to the list of claims in the JWT, thinking that maybe the claim is detected in the token, but this also did not work.  I've checked that the user has the claim in the first place, by using

```
var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(currentUser);
```

and the correct claim shows.  I tried adding the policy to other methods in other controllers, and I checked capitalisation and different names for the claim, with no luck.
What did I miss here to keep the "CanEdit" policy from working?

Edit:
Here's what I have for creating JWTs, if it helps:

```
public async Task<string> CreateToken(AppUser user)
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["jwtSecret"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
        
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.DisplayName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
        };
        var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
        claims.AddRange(userClaims);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor{
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = creds
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Comment: could you share an example jwt that satisfy `CanEdit` policy ?

Comment: please, use the use which has canEdit claim to login and then use  IsUser on a method and add inside that method  HttpContext.User with a breakpoint on it then check whether the current user has the canEdit claim

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. I added the JWT code in the post.  Does the policy check the AspNetUserClaims table in the database, or the JWT for the claim?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TarikGen's suggestion, I checked the claims in HttpContext.User and managed to see the issue.

The claim I had in the AspNetUserClaims table for "canEdit" actually had a claim type of "role", which was the root of the problem.  All I had to do was change the claim type to "canEdit" to fix the issue.

Extra note:
I did notice because of my mistake that "role" seems to be a keyword for the claim type, since the list of Claims in HttpContext.User shows a claim type of "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", instead of just "role".  Upon checking, I found that, had I made my policy to RequireClaim("role"), I would have been unauthorized because of this.